# Seria do StackOverflow uma saída de emergência?

Tags: debate

Quando alguém precisa de ajuda com alguma coisa de programação, a primeira coisa que ela irá fazer é pesquisar na internet ou em documentações das linguagens, quando não acha o que procura vai e pesquisa se há pergunta + resposta no StackOverflow, caso não ache o que procurava, vai lá e pergunta.

### Pessoas não querem perguntar, por quê?

Já senti isso, é normal em todo mundo sentir uma leve "vergonha" em não saber algo, até mesmo na sala de aula poucos levantam a mão para perguntar algo para o professor. Essa sensação das pessoas é uma coisa prejudicial tanto para elas tanto para a comunidade.

### Quero é responder, não quero perguntar!

Essas mesmas pessoas que tem vergonha das perguntar coisas simples para as mais complexas. O site não descrimina o conhecimento de ninguém, mas a pessoa consegue dar uma risada e um crítica por trás da tela, e para ser uma boa pessoa responder com clareza e ser gentil.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Ta, onde você quer chegar com isso?

Não vejo muitas pessoas fazendo perguntas, não do jeito que via antes, muitos hoje estão pesquisando na internet e obtendo suas respostas, não estão perguntando por quê? Vergonha? Falta de pesquisa? Falta de conhecimento ou uma leve gentileza para tentar ajudar o próximo? Temos que promover as pessoas à fazer perguntas. Quanto mais perguntas, mais respostas, e maior ainda a comunidade irá ser.

Comment: não entendi o título

Comment: @DanielOmine Se trocar "do" por "o" faz mais sentido, mas não estou certo se é isto que o AP quis dizer.

Comment: Podemos votar sobre o titulo da pergunta? Da forma como esta nao faz muito sentido (pelo menos para leitores PT-PT)?

Comment: Vote para retirar o "d".

Comment: Vote para deixar o "d"

Comment: Vote para perguntar ao RZ-8121 o que ele quis dizer. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pessoas pesquisam na internet e acham o SO. Elas acham o que procuram aqui. Cada dia é mais fácil achar alguma coisa aqui e ser exatamente o que quer. Então pra que perguntar algo que já existe? O SO está cumprindo o papel dele se as pessoas não precisam perguntar mais. Seja porque já tem a resposta, seja porque fez as pessoas já aprenderam e não precisam mais perguntar tanto (ainda que pessoalmente eu ache que que isto ocorra menos do que gostaria).

Eu não sei se entendi totalmente o objetivo da pergunta. E acho que seria legal as pessoas fazerem mais perguntas, até mesmo quando sabem a resposta.

Aí entramos em outra discussão. Algumas (poucas) pessoas aqui são contra e tentam desincentivar que estas perguntas sejam feitas. Não tenho poder para mudar isto, ainda que gostaria de ter.

As pessoas perguntarão quando elas sentirem necessidade. Acho que é feito tudo o que se pode para promover as perguntas. Se tem algo a mais que possa ser feito, basta sugerir.

Sinta-se à vontade pra perguntar. Se não sair jogando perguntas de qualquer jeito, faça várias! Quando não se tem um problema real nem sempre é fácil fazer uma pergunta tão boa. O problema real dá para a pessoa a necessidade, ela só precisa escrever bem sobre ela. Inventar uma necessidade é preciso um domínio maior sobre o assunto. Me parece que tem um limite diário de quantas perguntas pode fazer, mas é alto. Manda ver!

Comment: "E acho que seria legal as pessoas fazerem mais perguntas, até mesmo quando sabem a resposta." Boa iniciativa, infelizmente muitos não irão querer fazer isso para, pelo motivo, hmmmm vamos dizer, "ah, eu já sei como faço isso, pra que vou perguntar?" Ai então criamos um outro debate... Chega de debate por hoje, hehe

Comment: @RZ-8121 ainda a bem pouco tempo fiz isso [Como é que eu posso saber se o primeiro digito de uma string é um número?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111739/como-%C3%A9-que-eu-posso-saber-se-o-primeiro-digito-de-uma-string-%C3%A9-um-n%C3%BAmero) ;)

Comment: `Algumas (poucas) pessoas aqui são contra e tentam desincentivar que estas perguntas sejam feitas.` - Isso me lembra aquele caso da pergunta sobre linguagens, IDE e compiladores...

Answer (score 1):

Otimo questionamento, vou dar minha opinião PESSOAL aqui como um mero hobbysta em programacao mas que tem sede de conhecimento.

Primeiro um breve pitaco entre o antes e o depois ressaltando a MINHA VISAO das coisas.

Como pesquiso muito a principal diferença entre pesquisas de outros sites para o stack são as explicações. Enquanto outros eles explicam tim tim por tim tim , aqui no stack é mais direto ao ponto.

**Seria do StackOverflow uma saída de emergência?**

Sim, não desprezando a vasta gama de conteudo aqui produzido

**Pessoas não querem perguntar, por quê?**

Quanto entrei no stack para postar uma pergunta, me deparei com esse topico, mas ja com o pensando no que ia ter de resposta 
EX: veja a funcao file_put_content no manual php voce deve ribinborcar a porca da parafuzeta das arrays para entao papibaquigrafar as counts ...

Essas são as respostas que eu temo e ja presenciei muitas delas. Creio que a maioriam que perguntam algo querem é a solução do problema e não a solucao de como resolver o problema.

**Quero é responder, não quero perguntar!**

Na real as respostas são até mais cobradas do que as perguntas, pois voltando ao que falei sobre as perguntas já presenciei tambem muitas puxadas de orelhas por respostas que até eu mesmo daria a mesma. EX: o cara queria um contador, o cara postou um codigo gerado nesses sites online e resolveu o problema do outro, porem um comentarista deu um sermão que até me doeu na alma.

**Ta, onde você quer chegar com isso?**

Que sou feliz pelo stack ser o que é, e fazer a alegria da sociedade.

Comment: Entendi seu ponto de vista e faz sentido mesmo. A respeito da cobrança, é que se visa, além de ajudar a quem pergunta, é que tanto perguntas quanto respostas tenham qualidade suficiente para servirem de referencia para qualquer um com problema semelhante. As vezes uma resposta poderia ser dada colando um código e pronto, mas e se outra pessoa com problema semelhante, gostaria de entender como funciona? Fazer outra pergunta? As vezes uma ou 2 linha de explicação já esclarece a duvida de inúmeros que irão ler o conteúdo.